# If I can do all I need in a procedure why would I use a trigger at all?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, triggers

I have a general question about why I'd need a trigger if I can do the checks and such and validations in a procedure.?

Comment: A trigger is a PL/SQL unit that is stored in the database and (if it is in the enabled state) automatically executes ("fires") in response to a specified event.

Answer (score 2):

Stored procedures are meant to process records, and work on operations and data, which would otherwise have been difficult to perform in a sql query on its own.Eg: You can define your own user defined exceptions, handle file operations, call rest-api, etc inside the stored procedure.

Triggers on the other hand are part of the transaction boundary, and would be invoked on the INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE of entries in the table. A stored procedure can be invoked when a trigger is fired. There are triggers which are invoked on DDL commands also. A use case of using triggers, would be to audit records, (say populate  audit history of the changes to the table).

Some other features of,triggers, it can possibly get fired many times in oracle, check how this happens
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:237924300346045037

In your case of doing validations on data, i would first do the following. Ensure all validations are set up using constraints on the table, (check constraint, not null, unique ness etc).

If necessary create further validations using a stored procedure. Have that stored procedure get invoked using a trigger. I wouldnt do anything non-transaction in a trigger(eg: sending alert mails etc, as its in the transaction boundary, the trigger would have got fired even when you have rolled back the transaction)